# Visual Studio fast switching platform for entire solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have 6 projects in my `Universal Windows` solution. Some of then have referrence to other projects. What is the simple way to switch target platform in entire solution? 
For example, i have project `blahblah.Core` and `blablah.Infrastructure`. Second project got refference to first at path `...blahblah.Core\bin\Debug\x86`. To build solution for `ARM` i need to build `blahblah.Core` for `ARM`, then delete refference from `blablah.Infrastructure`, then add new one for `...blahblah.Core\bin\Debug\ARM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Solution **Properties >> Configuration** and you can manage or set build order from it for your solution and build entire solution

Answer (score 3):

> The fastest?

Save different configurations:

1. In the Build menu, click Configuration Manager.
2. In the Active solution platform box, select the platform you want your solution to target, or select <New> to create a new platform. Visual Studio will compile your application to target the platform that is set as the active platform in the Configuration Manager dialog box.

Ref: [How to: Configure Projects to Target Multiple Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165408.aspx)